# What is the word to describe a single object to represent the many?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

If I am writing a poem, I might use the word *peaches* to symbolize all fruit. Is there a specific word for this type of symbolism?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called *metonymy*. For example, *sword* for "war" or *Washington* for "the US Government".

Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonym

Comment: Thurber has a lovely hymn to metonymy, [“Here Lies Miss Groby”](http://books.google.ca/books?id=Guem4QpR0BwC&lpg=PA167&dq=thurber%20%22here%20lies%20miss%20groby%22&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q&f=false), in particular to the Container for the Thing Contained…

Comment: So is synecdoche a kind of metonymy?

Comment: From Michael Quinion at World Wide Words: worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-syn1.htm <<Both are figures of speech used in rhetoric. They’re not the same thing, though metonymy is often interpreted so widely that synecdoche can be regarded as a special case of it.>> There is a convention to choose the tighter of two hypernymic-hyponymic terms (an application of the 'principle of specificity'), so I'd go with synecdoche here - using the whole to reference the part (England win 2 - 0) or the part to reference the whole (Napoleon had 200 000 foot). _Boil a kettle_ is obviously metonymy but not synecdoche.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a suitable word outside the realm of literary criticism, you might consider *exemplar* especially if you're looking for the connotation of the single best representation of the many.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exemplar) gives the definition of:

> Something typical or representative of a class
>
> Something fit to be imitated

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "syndedoche" in the sense of the original question- use of a subset of something to represent the whole, e.g. "The colonel commanded two hundred horse", or "Fifty head of cattle"

As I understand it, metonymy is the use of something associated with the described object as a representation of it; "Hollywood" for the film industry, or "Wall Street" for the financial market.

Comment: I'd query 'horse' as a subset of 'horseman/horsemen' - this is surely metonymy and not synecdoche. _Horse_ represents _horseman_, not (horse + horseman). Compare _Jesse James and his five guns held up the stagecoach_. The head is a part of the neat; the horse is not a part of the horseman.