# Word for using example to refer to the whole

Tags: single-word-requests

I was talking with a friend about the word "portmanteau", noticing that it is itself a portmanteau (making it autological), but in particular its meaning seems to have nothing to do with the concept other than being an example of it.  If history had run a different course, we might be calling "smog" a blaxploitation.

I'm wondering if there is a word for words in which an example of the concept is used as the concept's name.  Would "synecdoche" be appropriate?  It doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: You mean beside *autological* ??

Comment: +1 for [Autological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) ^

Comment: I see where you guys are coming from, because what is a word besides its meaning... so I guess I am asking something more etymological?  Having a moment of zen about semantics

Comment: [Mondo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mondo) - *"The whole world can tell a snake from a dragon, but you cannot fool a Zen monk."* - Principia Discordia - : )

Comment: Related: [What is a catchy word that means (non-)self-descriptive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/), [Words that define a type of word and also obey that definition](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75870/), [What is the word to describe a single object to represent the many?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/), [What is the difference between a metonymy and a synecdoche?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/), and further questions linked from these.

Comment: @RegDwighт  Ahh thank you, _Metonymy_ fits the bill just right!

Comment: luqui, if you think "*Metonymy* fits the bill just right", you could post it as a self-answer and score up votes.

Answer (score 2):

*[Synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)* can refer to using an example to refer to the whole. For example, *coke* is used to refer to any cola.